# Why does Jetstream fail to install on laravel 8 on my PC

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I recently installed `laravel-8` and trying to install Laravel Jetstream for authentication following their [official documentation](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/installation.html#installing-jetstream).  It's returning the below error.

```
$ composer require laravel/jetstream
Using version ^1.6 for laravel/jetstream
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/jetstream
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 9 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking bacon/bacon-qr-code (2.0.3)
  - Locking dasprid/enum (1.0.3)
  - Locking jaybizzle/crawler-detect (v1.2.103)
  - Locking jenssegers/agent (v2.6.4)
  - Locking laravel/fortify (v1.7.2)
  - Locking laravel/jetstream (v1.6.3)
  - Locking mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib (2.8.34)
  - Locking paragonie/constant_time_encoding (v2.4.0)
  - Locking pragmarx/google2fa (8.0.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 9 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading paragonie/constant_time_encoding (v2.4.0)
 0/1 [>---------------------------]   0%
 1/1 [============================] 100%  - Installing dasprid/enum (1.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing bacon/bacon-qr-code (2.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing jaybizzle/crawler-detect (v1.2.103): Extracting archive
    Install of jaybizzle/crawler-detect failed
  - Installing paragonie/constant_time_encoding (v2.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing pragmarx/google2fa (8.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/fortify (v1.7.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib (2.8.34): Extracting archive
  - Installing jenssegers/agent (v2.6.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/jetstream (v1.6.3): Extracting archive
    0 [>---------------------------]    0 [>---------------------------]
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete C:\wamp\www\earnday/vendor/composer/18d01bbf\JayBizzle-Crawler-Detect-3efa286\src\Fixtures\Crawlers.php:
  This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed
```

What's the possible fix?

Comment: Does `composer diagnose` show any error

Comment: @Donkarnash Checking platform settings: The Windows OneDrive folder is not supported on PHP versions below 7.2.23 and 7.3.10.
Upgrade your PHP (7.3.5) to use this location with Composer. Every other option is OK

Comment: Try upgrading your php version

Comment: It's already working now, felt I needed to restart my computer after upgrading composer